# Delete all characters that are not either spaces, zeros or alphabetic characters

Tags: java, regex

i need to Delete all characters that are not either spaces, zeros or alphabetic characters in a string. My regular expression for this is `name.replaceAll("[^\\s0A-Z]//", "")`. This is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you also need to remove all Unicode letters? Note you have `/` at the end, it causes the major trouble, I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
name.replaceAll("[^\\s0a-zA-Z]", "")
```

this should work for you.